# golang debugger stops on empty lines - why?

Tags: go, intellij-idea, goland

I'm using Goland, the IntelliJ Go debugger. I've tried doing a `go run build.go clean` followed by a `go run build.go build`, and then `./pkg/cmd/grafana-server/debug`, however I still get my debugger stopping in weird places, namely, blank lines:

[image]

What causes the Go debugger to break on blank lines, and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you building the binary yourself using `go run` as described in the issue? If so, please switch to the IDE and use the built-in Run Configuration tools and launch a debug session from there. If the issue still happens, then please upgrade to Go 1.10.1 or newer, and make sure you are using GoLand 2018.1.1 or newer. If this still happens, please open an issue on the official tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go as logs are needed and this is not easy to share there.

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation for GoLand isn't very great when it comes to how to setup a debug configuration. The only thing I've been able to get going is `Attach to remote process...` - I'm on Go 1.10.1 and the newest version of GoLand.

Comment: I'm not sure which debugging feature are you using. There is a ` Go Remote ` Run Configuration which allows you to debug remote processing, and there is an ` Attach to Local Process ` option. Neither of them need special configuration.

If you are using Go 1.10+, then make sure you are building your binary with ` go build -gcflags="all=-N -l" your/package/name ` in order to turn off all optimizations used by Go and enable all the debugging information to be present in the binary.