# Why doesn't my Go debugger load all symbols, causing local variables to be missing from the debugger?

Tags: debugging, go, debug-symbols, delve, goland

I've built my binary with: `go build -gcflags "$gc_flags" -o ./bin/grafana-server ./pkg/cmd/grafana-server`, where `$gc_flags` is `'-N -l'`.

When I run this file, `./bin/grafana-server`, and attach to it in my debugger (Goland), not all of my symbols are loaded. Further, some breakpoints display the message:

> no code at /Users/.../file.go:186

The code I'd like to debug is below:

[image]

The section I've *added* to the original project is lines `186-199`. What you can see is that the execution has made it into the `for _, ..` loop (line 196), indicating that `query` has data, and we were able to pull data from the database using that `query` via `repo.Find(query)`. However, `query` is nowhere to be found in my debugger:

[image]

So I'm unsure what's going on at this point. I'm really really new to golang unfortunately; this is making it incredibly difficult for me to make any progress.

Comment: From what I understand in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49805029/golang-debugger-stops-on-empty-lines-why/ you are using Go 1.10+. When doing so, please use ` -gcflags="all=-N -l" ` in order to ensure that all debugged packages are properly compiled with the debug symbols on and no optimizations.

Comment: Thanks @dlsniper - I never came back to say this worked for me; it worked for me.

Comment: Happy to hear this works now. I'll add this as a proper response so it can be closed as answered.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When using Go 1.10 or newer, in order to have a better debugging experience and remove the optimizations the compiler does, you need to build the target application using `-gcflags="all=-N -l"`.

Before Go 1.10, you need to use `-gcflags="-N -l"`.

The IDE adds these flags automatically when compiling an application for debugging.